# Integrating Velocity equation vs. Acceleration equation

Tags: calculus, integration

I was trying to solve to solve part (d) of the 2015 A.P. Calculus BC FRQ Question 3 when I came across something confusing.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline \begin{array}{c}t \\
\text { (minutes) }\end{array} & 0 & 12 & 20 & 24 & 40 \\
\hline \begin{array}{c}v(t) \\\text { (meters per minute) }
\end{array} & 0 & 200 & 240 & -220 & 150 \\\hline\end{array}$$

3. Johanna jogs along a straight path. For $0 \leq t \leq 40,$ Johanna's velocity is given by a differentiable function $v$ Selected values of $v(t),$ where $t$ is measured in minutes and $v(t)$ is measured in meters per minute, are given in the table above.

(a) Use the data in the table to estimate the value of $v^{\prime}(16)$

(b) Using correct units, explain the meaning of the definite integral $\int_{0}^{40}|v(t)| d t$ in the context of the problem. Approximate the value of $\int_{0}^{40}|v(t)| d t$ using a right Riemann sum with the four subintervals indicated in the table.

(c) Bob is riding his bicycle along the same path. For $0 \leq t \leq 10,$ Bob's velocity is modeled by $B(t)=t^{3}-6 t^{2}+300,$ where $t$ is measured in minutes and $B(t)$ is measured in meters per minute. Find Bob's acceleration at time $t=5$

(d) Based on the model $B$ from part (c), find Bob's average velocity during the interval $0 \leq t \leq 10$.

In part (d), if we are finding the average velocity, should we integrate the equation for velocity or the equation for acceleration?

I had thought to use acceleration, because doesn't taking the integral of acceleration from 2 intervals gives us the total velocity between those intervals? Then, we could divide by the total distance of between the intervals to get the average velocity.

However, the solution key for that question integrates the velocity formula to get the average velocity. Could someone explain the meaning of the integral of velocity and acceleration between 2 intervals?

Comment: The entire question is rather long, so I just added a picture.

Comment: the average velocity is total distance divided by total time, that's why we integrate velocity to find total distance.

Comment: But then wouldn't integrating velocity and dividing over the length of the interval give us "average distance", instead of average velocity?

Comment: No, we are dividing something with the dimensions of distance by the *time* interval measured in minutes, the quantity would have dimensions of velocity.

Comment: "interval" means the range between two numbers - in particular the set of all numbers between the two. Those two numbers are called the "end points" of the interval. They are *not* called "intervals" themselves. One integrates over an interval, not "from 2 intervals". The end points of the interval being integrated are called the "upper and lower limits" of integration..